# Can I tell if a user has registered via my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using XFBML and the Registration plugin to assists users with registrations on my site.  I only want to display the Registration button if a user has not registered.  Is there any way to see if a user has registered with my site?

I only want to display this if a user hasn't registered via facebook.

```
<fb:login-button registration-url="/register_facebook.php" />
```

If a user has registered this button becomes a Facebook Login button which I want to handle else where so I only want to display it if they haven't registered.

Any one know if this is possible and if so how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: registering on your website means accessing your fb app right ? which means the first time app users, please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: correct, but I'm not sure how to get that info though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook js api has FB.getLoginStatus method.
This method returns a the user login status and also tell if the users is not authorized.
May be this could help.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        'appId': "APPID",
        'status': true,
        'cookie': true,
        'xfbml': true,
        'oauth': true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // The user has not authorized your app so far
            // do your stuff here (registration)
        } else {

        }
    });

};​
```